# Graphhopper - Loading routing information from a mounted obb file system error

Tags: java, android, routes, graphhopper

I'm trying to load the routing information from an obb file. I mounted the obb file correctly. 
I'm using the following code to load:

```
GraphHopper tmpHoppFOOT = new GraphHopper().forMobile(); 
tmpHoppFOOT.setCHShortcuts("fastest"); 
tmpHoppFOOT.setEncodingManager(new EncodingManager("FOOT")); 
tmpHoppFOOT.load(mapsFolder + currentAreaFOOT);
```

The load causes the following error message: 
AndroidRuntime(3498): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/obb/07f4c5780b38b1ae526b333f8087a627/FootPortugal-gh/edges (Read-only file system).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what OBB is but maybe this is a problem of how the file is opened in GraphHopper. I can imagine that

```
raFile = new RandomAccessFile(getFullName(), "r");
```

instead of the current:

```
raFile = new RandomAccessFile(getFullName(), "rw");
```

should help. See MMapDataAccess line 68 and recompile. If it helps, please create a new issue on github to make this configurable in GraphHopper.